# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model \“[object Object]\”.\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo este schema:

```
const PuestoSchema = new Schema(
  {
   //....more data
   reportaA: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Puesto"
    },

   //...
})


module.exports = mongoose.model("Puesto", PuestoSchema)
```

Se referencia a si mismo (Otros ids de documentos). Así que trato de popularlo con esto:

```
function autoPopulate(next) {
  let puestoSchema = mongoose.model('Puesto')

  this.populate("reportaA")


  next()
}

PuestoSchema
  .pre("findById", autoPopulate)
  .pre("findOne", autoPopulate)
  .pre("find", autoPopulate)
```

Pero obtengo este error.

> MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model \"[object
>   Object]\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)

Hay alguna manera de llamar este modelo para usarlo como referencia dentro de si mismo?

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta en el modelo indicar el schema a usar

```
function autoPopulate(next) {
  let puestoSchema = mongoose.model('Puesto') <-- Aquí
  // deberia ser: let puestoSchema = mongoose.model('Puesto', PuestoSchema)

  this.populate("reportaA")


  next()
}

PuestoSchema
  .pre("findById", autoPopulate)
  .pre("findOne", autoPopulate)
  .pre("find", autoPopulate)
```